# How to edit gradle to use Recyclerview

Tags: android, gradle, android-recyclerview

I want use recyclerview
I have gradle content:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tvcable"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable = false
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/mimetypes.default'
        exclude 'META-INF/mailcap.default'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0' 
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation files('libs/jtds-1.3.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/activation.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mail.jar')

    // I want implementation to use recyclerview
    // this line error
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

but error in last implementation
help me to solver it. thanks.

this line add to post question
this line add to post question
this line add to post question
this line add to post question

[image: Error message:]

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages, make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273) - the same reasoning applies to error messages as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All packages in **AndroidX** live in a consistent namespace starting
>   with the string **androidx**. The Support Library packages have been
>   mapped into corresponding **`androidx.*`** packages.

**FYI**

- Version **`28.0.0`** is the last release of the Support Library. There will
  be no more android.support library releases. All new feature
  development will be in the androidx namespace.

You should follow **[Migrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)**.

With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing project to **AndroidX** by selecting **`Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX`** from the menu bar.

Example for Androidx Recyclerview

```
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install Recyclerview and Cardview into your project is go activity_main.xml class and install it as shown in the picture, it will automatically add into gradle file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'